# Trying to make a put Request to update the JSON in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to make a put Request to update the JSON in Angular 8. This is the error which I am getting:

[image: error]

The HTML file :

```
<td>
    <a>
       <button *ngIf="enableEdit && enableEditIndex == i" (click)="enableEdit=false; cancel()" class="btn page-secondary-action-btn" >Cancel</button>
       <button *ngIf="enableEdit && enableEditIndex == i" id="saveBtn" class="btn page-primary-action-btn" (click)="saveSegment()" type="submit">Save</button>
       <i class="material-icons" *ngIf="i != enableEditIndex || enableEditIndex == null" (click)="enableEditMethod($event, i)" style="font-weight:bold; font-style:inherit ;color: green;">
           edit
       </i>
    </a>
</td>
```

Corresponding TS file :

```
saveSegment(data: blog) {
    console.log('editable data', data);
    this.blog.saveBlog(data).subscribe((Response) => {
        this.toastr.info('Updated successfully', 'blogs.id');
        this.route.navigate(['/admin/blogger']);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

And the Service file :

```
saveBlog(data: blog) {
    const body = {
      id: data.id,
      name: data.name,
      status: data.status,
      active: data.active,
      modifiedAt: data.modifiedAt,
    };
    return this.http.put(this.mainUrl + '/blog/' + data.id , body);
}
```

---

Here I am trying to edit and save the data to my web api, but the process is not working and hence getting the error as shown like in the image.

---

Comment: can you share the error  ?

Comment: i have attached a screenshot regarding the error which i am getting

Answer (score 1):

```
(click)="saveSegment(data)"
```

you have not pass the argument in the function

Like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let data of list">
  <button (click)="saveSegment(data)"> Click </button>
</li>
```

Comment: Tried that and still not working,The data is not getting updated

Comment: console.log('editable data', data);    in screen shot i have check that it is undefined you have to pass the data from where you are calling saveSegment function

Comment: I have already passed the *ngFor argument in the function.i missed to add the (click)="saveSegment(data)" in the code.Now the undefined error has been sorted and i am getting the console output but still the data is not getting updated in the backend.The same error is shown

Answer (score 0):

Data param is missing when you call saveSegment() from your html, just add it :

...

```
<button *ngIf="enableEdit && enableEditIndex == i" id="saveBtn" class="btn page-primary-action-btn" (click)="saveSegment(data)" type="submit">Save</button>
```

...

Comment: i have already tried that and still the data is not getting updated in the WEB API

Comment: Yeah Sure, you can find the whole code here in the below link.

Comment: I made some improvements, try and let me know your feedback https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x1jakq

Comment: Yeah i tried adding ng-container like in the given code,but still getting the same.Is there are any error in sending the put request?

Comment: copy the whole html and ts files not just the ng-container tag inside your table body, i tried it with mock api and it works

Comment: Tried the whole code and still the value is not updating in the API. i am getting the output in console like the value is changing there, but the value is not getting updated realtime

Comment: it's a backend issue in this case, check your api logic